# Deprecation errors before and blank screen after login in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, debian

I am installing phpmyadmin on a pristine server. This is the sequence/hierarchy:

Azure Instance -> Debian 11 -> php8.2 -> MariaDB -> phpMyAdmin

I did run the **mysql_secure_installation** and also ran the following:

```
sudo apt -y install wget php-cgi php8.2-mysqli php-pear php-mbstring libapache2-mod-php php-common php-phpseclib php-mysql
```

When I go to mydomain.com/phpmyadmin I get a bunch of errors.  Here's one example:

> Deprecation Notice in ./../../php/Twig/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php#40
> realpath(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is
> deprecated
>
> Backtrace
>
> FilesystemLoader.php#40: realpath(NULL)
> ./libraries/classes/Template.php#59:
> Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader->__construct(string
> '/usr/share/phpmyadmin//templates/')
> ./libraries/classes/Theme.php#103: PhpMyAdmin\Template->__construct()
> ./libraries/classes/Theme.php#174: PhpMyAdmin\Theme->__construct()
> ./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#306: PhpMyAdmin\Theme::load(
> string './themes/metro', string
> '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/./themes/metro/', )
> ./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#89:
> PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->loadThemes()
> ./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#129:
> PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->__construct()
> ./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#397:
> PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::getInstance() ./libraries/common.inc.php#315:
> PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::initializeTheme() ./index.php#23:
> require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

The only fix for the above seems to be to [suppress the errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72303941/phpmyadmin-deprecation-notice-php-8).  I also see errors in my apache error log.  There are many and they are similar, but here's one example:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You are not using
> binary logging in
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php:199\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php(199):
> mysqli->query()\n#1
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php(316):
> PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli->realQuery()\n#2
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php(1869):
> PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery()\n#3
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Menu.php(573):
> PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->fetchResult()\n#4
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Menu.php(107):
> PhpMyAdmin\Menu->_getServerTabs()\n#5
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Menu.php(70):
> PhpMyAdmin\Menu->_getMenu()\n#6
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Header.php(445):
> PhpMyAdmin\Menu->getDisplay()\n#7
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Response.php(323):
> PhpMyAdmin\Header->getDisplay()\n#8
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Response.php(336):
> PhpMyAdmin\Response->_getDisplay()\n#9
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Response.php(495):
> PhpMyAdmin\Response->_htmlResponse()\n#10 [internal function]:
> PhpMyAdmin\Response->response()\n#11 {main}\n  thrown in
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php on line 199

When I login in to phpmyadmin I get a blank screen. I have uninstalled and reinstalled several times, but I get the same errors and the blank screen.

MariaDB is running with the message **Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."** and I have tested that php is also working - with a test script and also using phpinfo();

Can you please help me determine the cause and perhaps a fix?

Comment: You need to install current version of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I thought I had, but apparently not.  It seems there is a problem that the latest version is not installed if installed using apt because it is not in the repositories.  I am researching how to upgrade now.  Thanx.

Comment: Yes, I was able to upgrade and it appears to have solved the problem  Should I post the process or delete this question?

Comment: I think you should post your answer below. It can help other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [noted](https://forum.howtoforge.com/threads/22-04-upgrade-blank-phpmyadmin-page.89964/#post-442170) by a phpmyadmin team member, there are [known issues](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17523#issuecomment-1139443175) with Debian/Ubuntu due to some packages not being included in the repository.

If you go to the first link, there are several fixes.  Mine relates to Debian and is reproduced below.  Here too there are multiple ways of doing it (again, see the first link), but I chose to use the one involving Backports.

Create a new sources file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bullseye-backports.list
```

Add the following line to the above file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
```

Then run:

```
apt-get update
```

to update the package list. Finally:

```
apt-get install -t bullseye-backports phpmyadmin
```

That should do it.  Another solution is to uninstall and then manually install the latest version from the [phpmyadmin website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/).  That's what I should have done in the first place. :-)